# iOS Swift 2.1 - Error Handling using Try Catch

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to do Error handling using swift 2.1,

The following scenario,

```
var test: NSArray! = ["Test1", "Test2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    do{
        try testing()
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

}

func testing() throws {

    print(test.objectAtIndex(7))
}
```

At the above case, My application crashes & saying terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException but I am expecting the control is supposed to be inside the Catch block instead of crash.

May I know the solution for this. Can anybody please do the needful on this

Comment: The Do-Try-Catch system only catches *errors*, it doesn't catch *exceptions*.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can make that work is to throw an error (as Eric D. pointed out in the comments):

**Playground:**

```
enum ArrayError : ErrorType{
  case OutOfBounds
}

class SomeClass {

  var test: NSArray! = ["Test1", "Test2"]

  func testCode() {

    do{
      try testing(3)
    } catch let error{
      print("error = \(error)") // for index 3 this would print "error = OutOfBounds\n"
    }

  }

  func testing(index: Int) throws -> String {

    guard index < test.count else{
      throw ArrayError.OutOfBounds
    }

    return test[index] as! String
  }

}

let sC = SomeClass()
sC.testCode()
```